# PnPPowerShell cmdlets throw "The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:00:30"

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell

Lately, I've noticed that Cmdlets such as Get-PnPListItem, Get-PnPFile and Get-PnPProperty throw the error ***The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:00:30. Increase the timeout value passed to the call to Request or increase the SendTimeout value on the Binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a
longer timeout.***

At first I was only getting this with Get-PnPFile but no with the others as well.
Has anybody experienced this lately or has an explanation/workaround for this?

Using the latest **3.1.1809.0 SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline**.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest release version of the SharePoint PnP PowerShell Online is 3.2.1810.0, install this and check if it works.

[SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.msi](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell/releases/download/3.2.1810.0/SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline.msi)